# Get row number for prediction with caret

Tags: r, r-caret, predict

I use caret a lot for my machine learning tasks in R and I like it a lot.

But I face the following problem:

- I train a model in caret, say a linear regression with `lm()`
- When I want to score new data, I do: `predict(model, new_data)`
- When `new_data`contains missing values in my predictors, predict returns no prediction, instead of say `NA`

Is it possible to either:

- return a prediction for all rows in new_data with a prediction of `NA` when it is not possible or
- return predictions + the row number of the dataframe the prediction corresponds to?

E.g. like the mlr-package does with an id-column that shows which row the prediction corresponds to:
[image]

Here is the link to the mlr-predict page with more details:
[mlr-package: predict with row-id](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/predict/index.html)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the cases with missing values prior to running `caret::train()` by creating a new column with the row names in your data set, since these default to the row numbers in the data frame.

Using the `Sonar` data set from the `mlbench` package as an illustration:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
library(caret)
set.seed(95014)

# add row numbers
Sonar$rowId <- rownames(Sonar)
# create training & testing data sets

inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list=FALSE)
training <- Sonar[inTraining,]
testing <- Sonar[-inTraining,]
# set column 60 to NA for some values in test data
testing[48:51,60] <- NA
testing[!complete.cases(testing),"rowId"]
```

...and the output:

```
> testing[!complete.cases(testing),"rowId"]
[1] "193" "194" "200" "206"
```

You can then run `predict()` on the rows in the test data set that have complete cases. Again using the `Sonar` dataset with a random forest model and 3 fold cross validation to expedite processing:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 3)
fit <- train(x,y, method="rf",data=Sonar,trControl = fitControl)
predicted <- predict(fit,testing[complete.cases(testing),])
```

Another way to handle this situation is to use an imputation strategy to eliminate the missing values for the independent variables in your model. My article on Github, [Strategies for Handling Missing Values](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/gen-handlingMissingValues.md) links to a number of research papers on this topic.

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer! Using complete.cases is certainly an option, but sometimes my dataset contains columns that contain missing values, but the columns are not used in training. So I would need to remove those columns first, before I could use your solution. I would prefer to know given dataset A, which rownumber in A a prediction corresponds to without changing the underlying dataset.

Comment: @Christoph - You could subset the columns in your test data set with `colnames()` on the output model, and then use `complete.cases()` on the remaining columns to avoid deleting cases from the test data set where columns not present in the model are missing.

Comment: Hey, sry for the late reply. Yes, I could do that, but that requires quite a bit of additional code and it would require me to filter missing rows ahead of time else I might not be able to correctly match e.g. a date column with the prediction made. I would rather I get a prediction vector with the same length as the input data with NAs when no prediction is possible or an ID that shows which row the prediction corresponds to.

Comment: @Christoph - You can make requests for new features in caret at the [Issues page](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues) of the caret Github repository. If this feature is really important, you can fork the source from the [caret repository](https://github.com/topepo/caret) and code it yourself.

Comment: I will. I was afraid that the feature already exists and I am just not able to find it... Thx for your help!